# Is there an 'Editing Finished" signal for a QListWidget?

Tags: qt, signals, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` control for which I have a slot for the `selectionChanged` signal. The list is configured for multi-selection.  The slot is getting called while the mouse button is still down while the user is dragging to select multiple items.  I don't want to process the changes until the mouse button is released. What I really need is some sort of Editing Finished signal, although not necessarily one that requires that focus on the control is lost.  Can you give this novice some guidance, please ?

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#signals

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfocusevent.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimerevent.html

Using some combination of the events above, or the signals already built into your `QListWidget`, go and start a "done editing timer".  When there is another click or edit, reset the timer.  On the timeout of the timer, do your calculations or filtering.

For example:

```
subclass QListWidget.

initialize the timer (singleshot, set at 750 ms or so)

itemSelectionChanged => start the timer

mousePressEvent => stop the timer

mouseReleaseEvent => start the timer

keyPressEvent => (shift),(ctrl), or (arrows) => stop the timer
keyReleaseEvent => (all keys released) => start the timer

focusOutEvent => start the timer

focusInEvent => stop the timer

connect the timer's timeout signal to a custom signal `myEditingFinished`
```

outside of your `QListWidget`, connect to its `myEditingFinished` signal to `runDatabaseQuery` or whatever you are trying to do.

Hope that helps.